# sort a multidimensional array according to 3 keys (day,month,year) in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this one ( each $orders[$userid] array has multiple arrays of orders)

```
foreach($orders[$userid] as $order){
    print_r($order);
}
```

This is the first user's orders grouped by date,month,year

```
Array ( [id] => 409079 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 30 [final_total] => 29.1 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 1 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 2198.2999696731567 )

Array ( [id] => 410744 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 175 [final_total] => 165 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 2 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 2619.799982070923 )

Array ( [id] => 412268 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 300 [final_total] => 293 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 3 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 4413.400000572205 )

Array ( [id] => 405860 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 10 [final_total] => 9.8 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 30 [month] => 10 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 352.5999994277954 )

Array ( [id] => 407500 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 85 [final_total] => 84.5 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 31 [month] => 10 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 1135.1000022888184 )
```

As you see older dated are displayed after recent dates. The question is how to sort this multidimensional array to display old dates then recent dates like this

```
Array ( [id] => 405860 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 10 [final_total] => 9.8 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 30 [month] => 10 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 352.5999994277954 )

Array ( [id] => 407500 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 85 [final_total] => 84.5 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 31 [month] => 10 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 1135.1000022888184 )

Array ( [id] => 409079 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 30 [final_total] => 29.1 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 1 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 2198.2999696731567 )

Array ( [id] => 410744 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 175 [final_total] => 165 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 2 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 2619.799982070923 )

Array ( [id] => 412268 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 300 [final_total] => 293 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 3 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 4413.400000572205 )
```

Comment: please, use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of `var_dump` next time. while `var_dump` is great for representation, but you cannot copy/paste it. so for showing needed results it is ok, but for showing source data it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Please use code:

```
foreach ($orders as $key => $row) {
    $year[$key]  = $row['year'];
    $month[$key] = $row['month'];
    $day[$key] = $row['day'];
}

array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $month, SORT_ASC, $day, SORT_ASC, $orders);
```

Comment: you mean:
foreach($orders[$userid] as $order){
    foreach ($orders as $key => $row) {
    $year[$key]  = $row['year'];
    $month[$key] = $row['month'];
    $day[$key] = $row['day'];
}

array_multisort($year, SORT_ASC, $month, SORT_ASC, $day, SORT_ASC, $orders);
}
???

Comment: $orders will be your array like:  

$orders = Array ( [id] => 409079 [user_id] => 26017 [total] => 30 [final_total] => 29.1 [order_status_id] => 1 
[day] => 1 [month] => 11 [year] => 2016 [amount2] => 2198.2999696731567 )

Comment: still getting it wrong older dates come after recent dates

Answer (score 0):

While in more complex situations you would use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), in this case, you can reduce the problem to sort only by one value. The 
`'year'`, `'month'` and `'day'` are basically **parts of the date**. Using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function you can do the following:

```
$dateToTimestamp = function (array $order) {
    $day = $order['day'];
    $month = $order['month'];
    $year = $order['year'];

    return strtotime("$day-$month-$year");
};

usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($dateToTimestamp) {
    return $dateToTimestamp($a) - $dateToTimestamp($b);
});
```

One thing to pay attention with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) you cannot really set a locale in order to recognize which part of the string is a day, month, or year. In one of PHP manual comments, there is a trick to compensate this. In our case, the use of dash separator ensures the order.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2cf072f14a63d7cf17a2d94620c21c2abd892738).